# Keras (fit_generator) и TensorBoard

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Пытаюсь вызвать `TensorBoard` при обучении с помощью `fit_generator`

И получаю ошибку

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,200,200,3]
     [[{{node input_1}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,200,200,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Код

```
t_Board = TensorBoard(log_dir= content_drive + 'save/tb_logs', histogram_freq=1, write_images=True)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data = val_generator,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks = [t_Board ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorBoard в keras не может работать histogram